Why is my TensorFlow script running every line 32 times when executed by a GPU supercomputer?
I have a fairly simple TensorFlow model which I've been trying to run on a supercomputer which has several GPUs. It runs seamlessly on my laptop, however, on the supercomputer it appears to run every line 32 times, resulting in an output file that contains phrases like "DFs loaded" and "Data normalized" again and again. Once it gets to the building of the neural network, it prints errors like these over and over and then stops running:
2024-04-26 20:07:47.537408: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:753] failed to allocate 20.40GiB (21908291584 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2024-04-26 20:07:47.537383: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:753] failed to allocate 28.35GiB (30439505920 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2024-04-26 20:07:47.537395: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:753] failed to allocate 24.94GiB (26775781376 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory

Has anybody encountered this before? I'm using a Slurm scheduler to set the script going, also with fairly basic parameters:
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --account=XXXXX
#SBATCH --time=0:30:0
#SBATCH --partition=test
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --mem=512G

# Activate Conda environment
export CONDADIR=/nobackup/projects/XXXXX/$USER
source $CONDADIR/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate tf-env

module load cuda/12.0.1
export XLA_FLAGS="--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir=$CUDA_HOME"

module load gcc
module load openmpi/4.0.5
xxxx-mpirun python3 NN-test.py

Can anyone see anything in here that might be causing this issue?
This is the content of NN-test.py too:
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.regularizers import l2

# Build your model, compile it, and train it here

basePath = '/nobackup/XXXX'

# Concatenate all dataframes into one
fullData = pd.read_csv(f'{basePath}/TestMale-MFCC.csv')

print("DFs loaded!")

datasetSize = len(fullData)
print(datasetSize)
fullData = fullData.sample(datasetSize)

# Prepare the inputs (X) and labels (y)
# Assuming that the gender is stored in a column named 'gender' and it's binary encoded (0 for male, 1 for female)
X = fullData.iloc[:, 3:].values
y = fullData['gender'].values
print("Randomised!")

# Normalize the features
scaler = StandardScaler()  # or MinMaxScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print("Normalised!")

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
print("Sets made")

# Neural Network Model Definition
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(500, input_shape=(700,)),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Activation('relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),  # Increased dropout rate

    layers.Dense(500),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Activation('relu'),
    #layers.Dropout(0.5),  # Increased dropout rate

    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

print("Model made!")

optimiser = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=10, verbose=1, min_lr=0.000001)

early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    patience=100,
    verbose=0,
    mode='auto',
    restore_best_weights=True
)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1500, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])

Thank you!

What is the content of NN-test.py?

@mhovd Thanks for the question. I've edited my original post to add the content of NN-test.py

Is your machine a 32 core machine ?

why are you using mpirun if there is no distributed training happening? that might be the problem

@KeshavBiyani I believe so, yes

@Dr.Snoopy Ah okay, thanks, I'm trying it without now...

@Dr.Snoopy So I'm finding that, when I remove mpirun and set it going with 1 GPU and 1 node, it runs fine but it's very slow. However, when I increase to 2 GPUs, it seems to sit in the queue forever. So it seems like I maybe need mpirun for handling multiple GPUs?

@Dr.Snoopy Apologies, spoke too soon. It's running now with gpu:2
